# How to upload a local video file from shared hosting to Youtube via API

Tags: php, laravel, youtube-api

Currently, I'm working on my web page in the local environment and I managed to upload video from my local driver to Youtube via Youtube API. You can see that the file path is standard for every video:

```
$videoResponse = $service->videos->insert(
    'snippet,status',
    $video,
    array(
      'data' => file_get_contents("D:\Video Archive\\" . Carbon::now()->toDateString() . ".mp4"),
      'mimeType' => 'application/octet-stream',
      'uploadType' => 'multipart'
     )
);
```

My question is, how can I target the same file when I deploy my webpage into shared hosting?

Comment: You move `D:\Video Archive` to a real path on your server. Relative paths would be a good use-case here. Possibly full paths if needed like `/var/www/yoursite.com/video_archive/...`

Comment: That is the real path. The file will be on my computer, not on the server.

Comment: Unless you build a file sharing bridge between your computer and your server then it wouldn't able to be accessed.

Comment: If you want this to upload things from your local machine then why do you even need shared hosting at all?

Comment: I want to do from my web page's admin panel, because I create the description and tags in my admin panel and I need the video ID there after upload. After I got video ID, I share it on Slack. So if I could do that, I would be able to create a pipeline to make this process done automatically and get rid of too many copy-paste tasks.

Comment: But you could do all that from a local application on your machine. Or you could upload from the local machine and then send the video ID to your website via a separate request

Comment: Of course, I can do that, but what is the point of using two different applications to deal with such a simple job? I want to control everything from a single app.

Comment: Because of networks. You can't control your local machine from the web unless something separate is installed on it to run the upload. It's just a fact if life. So you need to adjust your system architecture to deal with that